# how to find out the current NODE_ENV the express app is running under?

Tags: node.js, express

I was just wondering if i can find out what is the current value of `NODE_ENV` (i.e. either development or production) in a express code (so i can't use `app.configure('production' function(){})`).

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try `process.env.NODE_ENV`

It should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Just a subtlety, do if(!process.env.NODE_ENV) to test for development, since by default it is development unless NODE_ENV is defined

Comment: Is it possible to figure this out with shell commands somehow? I started the server and would like to type a command that outputs the value of NODE_ENV (either `production` or  `development`).

Answer (score 11):

Within your express script, `app.settings.env` should house that value.

Comment: i just saw that, but the problem is this is in another file, and to make testing easier, i want to do something different for dev and prod.

Comment: then send the app variable to your functions... `require('myfile')(app)`

Comment: Each request object contains the instance of `app` so you can use `req.app.settings.env === 'development'` from within your handler.