# Undefined exception when getting cookie

Tags: node.js, cookies, express

I am playing with node and was trying to set a cookie on a request but am getting an undefined exception.  Here is my sample application

```
var express = require('express');

var app = module.exports = express();

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

app.configure('production', function(){
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.cookie('cart', 'test', {maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true});

    res.send("OK");
});

app.get('/users/:id', function(req, res) {
    var s = req.params.id;

    res.send('testcookie: ' + req.cookies.cart);
});    


app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

I can validate in Charles that I am getting and returning the cookies:

[image]

But the result whenever I go to `/users:id` (where :id is obviously some number) I get a message saying the cookies object is undefined.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cart' of undefined
    at c:\Projects\app\app.js:29:42
    at callbacks (c:\Projects\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:161:37)
    at param (c:\Projects\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:135:11)
    at param (c:\Projects\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:132:11)
    at pass (c:\Projects\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:142:5)
    at Router._dispatch (c:\Projects\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:170:5)
    at Object.router (c:\Projects\app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10)
    at next (c:\Projects\app\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:199:15)
    at Object.expressInit [as handle] (c:\Projects\app\node_modules\express\lib\middleware.js:31:5)
    at next (c:\Projects\app\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:199:15)
```

I've read all the other SO questions about putting the `cookieParser` above the other middleware, and from all accounts this example SHOULD work, but I'm at a loss as to what is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, turns out that it has to do with how I set up `app.configure`.  The configure callback function wasn't getting called because the internals of app configure weren't calling the initialization function for the `production` ENV even though I thought it was explicitly set above.

To fix that, I changed the `process.env.NODE_ENV` to `app.settings.env` and everything started to work.

Found that info here: [how to find out the current NODE_ENV the express app is running under?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441287/how-to-find-out-the-current-node-env-the-express-app-is-running-under)